# Usar LIMIT junto com LEFT JOIN em mais de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela `anuncios`, na qual quero listar os `anuncios` do usuário juntamente com as `imagens`, estou tentando com a `query` abaixo, porém se tiver `5 imagens` cadastradas no `anuncio`, na tabela ele vai exibir 5 vezes, tem como limitar as imagens?

**Query**:

```
"select a.*, u.nome as nome_usuario, i.thumb as nome_imagem from anuncios a 
 left join usuarios u on u.id = a.id_usuario left join imagens i on 
 i.id_anuncio = a.id where id_usuario = '{$idUsuario}'";
```

Comment: voce tentou com LIMIT e nao deu certo? onde colocou o LIMIT? o que voce tentou até agora?

Comment: Tentei colocar o LIMIT em tudo quanto é lugar na query e nao funciona haha =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue sua query , transforme ela numa subquery e aplique LIMIT na query "pai", algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo que irá trazer apenas 1 registro:

```
    select * FROM ( 
      select a.*, 
     u.nome as nome_usuario, 
     i.thumb as nome_imagem from anuncios a 
    left join usuarios u on u.id = a.id_usuario 
    left join imagens i on i.id_anuncio = a.id 
      where id_usuario = '{$idUsuario}' 
) 
      LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimento utilizar no final da sua query a cláusula:

```
GROUP BY u.id_usuario, i.thumb
```

Ficaria algo assim:

```
SELECT a.*,
       u.id_usuario,
       u.nome AS nome_usuario,
       i.thumb AS nome_imagem 
FROM   anuncios a
LEFT JOIN usuarios u ON (u.id = a.id_usuario)
LEFT JOIN imagens i ON (i.id_anuncio = a.id)
WHERE  id_usuario = :id_usuario 
GROUP BY u.id_usuario, i.thumb;
```